# What can be said about the kernel of an elliptic operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, elliptic-operators

If $L$ is an elliptic operator, can we say anything about the dimension of the Kernel of $L$? If so, is there any technique that resembles the "variation of parameters" for ODEs to solve an equation of the form
$$
Lu=f\qquad\text{in }\mathbb{R}^N?
$$
I imagine that the answer in general is negative. However, is there any known condition on $L$ and $f$ such that the answer is affirmative? Are there any references treating this argument?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: On what spaces does $L$ operate?
Besides, you only need to consider $f=0$ if you are interested in the Kernel.

Comment: Let's say that $L$ operates on $H^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. You're right, we can consider the presence of $f$ only related to the second question about the variation of parameters' technique.